# How can I direct to different apps with different logins in Django project?

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, web-applications

I have different apps for different clients in a Django project. And I have a login page. A client can log in and the login credentials will direct to the respective app. Something like the app is created for a particular client and other clients can't access to that particular app.

How can I do that? I am confused in redirecting to the particular app in **urls.py** in Django main project folder *(not in urls.py of each app)*.

Comment: Shouldn't the login page determine where to redirect the user?

Comment: YES !!!!!!!!!!!!